# where is the best subview init in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
}
```

this is init when class new

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView :UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView()
    }
}
```

this is init when class new
and this is init when view add in window
which one is the best way,and is there any different

Comment: Neither add the view to the actual view controller?  I'd say the best is put it in the xib and add an outlet.  The difference here is pretty trivial.

Comment: I disagree with the downvote @KevinDiTraglia. Yes, the subview was not added in the example code, but that was not the point of the question. Also, yes, to you the difference may be trivial, but sometimes even the best of us overlook the semantics behind method/class naming. That's one of the usual ways code smells start. And to be honest, everyone introduced code smells at some point of time ;)

Comment: @JanBrinker I didn't downvote, but I vote to close, because in general, we discourage open ended and opinion based question. Pretty much every _what is the best way_ to do something falls into this category. We have [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) for discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either suggest option 1:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView = UITableView()
}
```

In this case (Kevin mentioned in the comment to your question), you still need to `self.addSubview(tableView)` somewhere.

Or something else:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let tableView :UITableView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        tableView = UITableView()
        self.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Must be implemented aswell
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I would *not* suggest initializing the view in `viewDidLoad`. Why? Look at the name of the function. View DID load. That implies that this function is called when the view and all its subviews already are initialized. Now look at that last word again. *Initialized*. Well, that's what we want do do. Initialize the view and all its subviews.. now what kinds of methods do we have for that.. oh, there is `init`.

Using `viewDidLoad` makes a lot of sense for setting up the properties of the subviews, setting the constraints and so on (maybe calling `self.addSubview(tableView)` for example). But not for initializing the subviews themselves.

Now, if you go with the option of overriding the init methods, you *need* to override the constructor `init(coder:)` aswell. The Swift compiler will complain otherwise. By default you can let Xcode insert a stub that just crashes, but well, this is not very nice, so you would need to implement the method for real to make sure no weird states come up. So in turn you would also need to implement a method that encodes the view so it can be decoded with the new `init` method. `encodeWithCoder(_ aCoder: NSCoder)`. Sure, you can just go with the Xcode default that inserts a `fatalError` in that constructor, but it's not *nice*.

Comment: You do know that `init?(aDecoder:)` is used by xib or Storyboard. It will crash if the `fatalError` is still there. There's nothing wrong with initializing subviews dynamically at any stage. The `viewDidLoad` is a common place since it's called only once in the `ViewController` lifecycle. There use to be a `didUnload`, but now, the `deinit` is the closing end of the view controller. If I add an observer in `didLoad`, I'll remove it in `deinit`.

Comment: Yes, I do know that. But looking at the question I don't see an `@IBOutlet`, that's why I didn't include that in my answer.

Comment: Damn, I couldn't edit anymore: I didn't state that you "may not" init views in `viewDidLoad`, but I do say it's a good idea to look at method names and think about implications. Are you doing something that conflicts with the naming? Are you giving a twist to the naming? Clarity is the point. As to `viewDidLoad` only being called once: so is `init` ;) with the additional benefit of not introducing any unclearness. The difference isn't big, but it's there.